# I have a couple of questions on shelves in the module pickle?

Tags: python

**The first question**: After what should I pass as the first argument when opening a new shelf. I have looked around and seen a few different parameters.

```
s = shelve.open("pickles2.dat")  
shelve.open(filename, flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False) 

database = shelve.open(filename.suffix)
```

What is the standard I should follow?

**second question**: After opening adding new data to a shelf and using the shelve.close() method. How do you open that same shelf to write in more things?  For example say I used the same shelve I opened above closed it and now I want to open it again. Would I used the same line of code as the very first time I opened the shelve?

```
s = shelve.open("pickles2.dat")
```

Comment: That tile will not work! You should put some part of the questions in the title.

Comment: Have you... tried it?  (yes, just reopen the shelf, that's the whole point of serialization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question: `flag`, `protocol` and `writeback` are optional arguments. So as long as you are happy about default values you do not want to list or modify them.

For the second question: yes, you open it again!

Here is an example:

```
import shelve
s = shelve.open("pickles2.dat")
s['1plus1']='2'
s['2plus2']='4'
s.close()

s = shelve.open("pickles2.dat")
print s['1plus1']
s['3plus3']='zero'
s.close()

s = shelve.open("pickles2.dat")
print s
```

Output:

```
2
{'1plus1': '2', '3plus3': 'zero', '2plus2': '4'}
```